# MetroFramework - scrollbar só estiliza após evento de click

Tags: c#, winforms, metroframework

Bom galera, está ocorrendo um bug no layout que quando eu carrego a Grid, o scrollbar (horizonal e/ou vertical) só é estilizado depois de algum evento de click. Por exemplo:

Scrollbar antes do evento:

[image: Scrollbar antes do evento]

Scrollbar após evento

[image: Scrollbar após evento]

Estou utilizando a framework [Modern UI MetroFramework](http://denricdenise.info/2014/09/how-to-use-winforms-modern-ui/)

Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode ser?

Comment: Eu uso o MetroChart, em algumas situações os gráficos não carregam caso eu faça passo-a-passo lógico.

Por exemplo: 

1 - Crio uma série de dados

2 - Seto o itemsSource da série com a lista.

3 - Adiciono essa série no chart. 

Fazendo desse modo ele não carrega o gráfico, para carregar preciso inverter os passos 2 e 3.

Comment: Que estranho. No meu caso acabei percebendo que não é o evento de Click, e sim de Resize ou de Scroll da barra. Vou simular um scroll do usuário e ver o que acontece.